# IPhone Tasks Using Objective

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have few tasks which I need to get done using Objective-C for IPhone App. I have a View which shows UIActivityIndicator and UIImage and does following:

1. Checks a URL (http://....com/service...) and reads XML and act after it.
2. Plays video streaming when clicked on UIImage.
3. Switch to another UIView.

Is/Are there guide(s) from where I can read to implement these things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

**For xml**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**For Streaming Video**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1634/_index.html

**For UIView Management**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html